# passing paramters using ksoap2 to .net web service, always passes nulls (empty) values

Tags: android

I am new to android applications,I am using Ksoap2 to access .Net webservice and The call is executed just fine without parameters. But with parameters I am getting Empty.
I followed all the steps provided in sites. I tried everything possible but no luck so far. I hope 
someone can help,

```
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.agilelearning.com/GetProvincelist1"; 
 private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetProvincelist1 "; 
 private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.agilelearning.com" ; 
 private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.24/Service.asmx";



//Method executed when Province is selected
 private OnItemSelectedListener selectListener = new OnItemSelectedListener()
     {
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
         {
             try
             {
 ArrayList<String> districts=new ArrayList<String>();
                int Provinceid=position+1;//parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();          
                SoapObject request1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);                              
                request1.addProperty("Provincename","East Province");
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope1 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
                envelope1.dotNet = true; 
                envelope1.setOutputSoapObject(request1); 
                HttpTransportSE at = new HttpTransportSE(URL); 
                at.debug = true;
                at.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
                at.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope1);               
                SoapObject rs = (SoapObject)envelope1.getResponse();                int count=rs.getPropertyCount();
                for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                {
                    districts.add(rs.getProperty(i).toString());
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> aa;         
                aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(home1.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, districts); 
                aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sd.setAdapter(aa); 
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
                 MessageBox("No Districts found");
             }

         }
```

Comment: This happens when the elements for the parameters are not in the correct xml namespace, which namespace to use will depend on how your .NET service is configured. (You can work this out from the WSDL).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case the parameter name I've send from android was different from the parameter name expected by my web service.

They have to be the same.

```
    request.addProperty("DeviceId",uid); --add parameter from android


    [WebMethod]
    public LoginResult Login(string DeviceId) ---web service
    {
       .......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, reformatting your code so it's more readable....

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.agilelearning.com/GetProvincelist1";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetProvincelist1";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.agilelearning.com";
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.24/Service.asmx";

//Method executed when Province is selected
private OnItemSelectedListener selectListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        try {
            ArrayList districts=new ArrayList();
            int Provinceid=position+1;
            //parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            SoapObject request1 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request1.addProperty("Provincename","East Province");
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope1 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope1.dotNet = true;
            envelope1.setOutputSoapObject(request1);
            HttpTransportSE at = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            at.debug = true;
            at.setXmlVersionTag("");
            at.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope1);

            SoapObject rs = (SoapObject)envelope1.getResponse();
            int count=rs.getPropertyCount();
            for(int i=0;i aa;
                aa = new ArrayAdapter(home1.this,
                                      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                      districts);
            aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sd.setAdapter(aa);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox("No Districts found");
        }
    }
};
```

The issue is this line:
                envelope1.dotNet = true;

You can see in lines 404-407 of [SoapSerializationEnvelope.java](http://ksoap2.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ksoap2/trunk/ksoap2/ksoap2/src/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapSerializationEnvelope.java?revision=131&view=markup) that it adds them. THe documentation says "[Set this variable to true for compatibility with what seems to be the default encoding for .Net-Services. This feature is an extremely ugly hack. A much better option is to change the configuration of the .Net-Server to standard Soap Serialization!](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/serialization/SoapSerializationEnvelope.html#dotNet)" Sounds like ksoap2 just hacked something in that seemed to work in one instance.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ksoap are you using? I am the project owner of the ksoap2-android project on google code and just released a new version 2.5.2. The .net= true works just fine btw.

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

You should probably set a debug point at the getResponse call and see what you get back.

If you get a stack trace it would be good to see that too.

Oh and btw. you dont want to do a call like that on the UI thread. You should move it to be done in an AsyncTask.